# Create List<CustomObject> from List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a CustomObject, say defined with following attibutes:

```
string Name {get;set;}
string EmailAddress{get;set;}
```

Also, I have a separate `List<string>` that contains all 'names'

I want to populate `List<CustomObject>` with each CustomObject having its name assigned from `List<string> names`.

How can I achive this using Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var strList = new List<string>();
var coList = strList.Select(item => new CustomObject() {Name = item}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
List<CustomObject> customObjectList = 
    (from item in stringList
    select new CustomObject { Name = item, EmailAddress = String.Empty }).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for omitting the `()` and spacing the object initializer properly.
-1 for using query-style where it's absolutely not needed and further perverting it by wrapping it in parenthesis to use `.ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: removed rubbish class declaration

```
IList<string> names = new List<string> { "first name", "second name" };
IList<SampleObject> myObjects = 
    names.Select(x => new SampleObject { Name = x }).ToList();
```