# Create List<CustomObject> from List<OtherObject>, removing duplicates.

Tags: c#, linq

There's a very related question: [Create List<CustomObject> from List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6519862/161052) however it doesn't deal with removing duplicates at the same time.

I have the following class examples:

```
class Widget
{
    public string OwnerName;
    public int SomeValue;
}

class Owner
{
    public string Name;
    public string OtherData;
}
```

I'd like to create a list of owners based on a list of Widgets, but only unique owner names.

Here is what I tried:

```
List<Owner> Owners = MyWidgetList.Select(w => new Owner { Name = w.OwnerName }).Distinct().ToList();
```

The problem is that there are repeats in the resulting list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is why we love SO, right? :)

Comment: @Gluip: isn't that a nick cage movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` for your object to define what equality is for your custom type.  Otherwise it compares based on the reference itself.

This is because the LINQ extension methods use the `IEqualityComparer` interface to compare objects.  If you don't define a custom comparer (which you can do by creating a separate class that implements `IEqualityComparer<Owner>`) it will use the default equality comparer, which uses the class's `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` definition.  Which, if you don't override them, does reference comparisons on `Equals()` and returns the default object hash code.

Either define a custom `IEqualityComparer<Owner>` (since you're calling distinct on a sequence of Owner) or add a `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` for your class.

```
public class Owner
{
    public string Name;
    public string OtherData;

    public override Equals(object other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        if (other == null)
            return false;

        // whatever your definition of equality is...
        return Name == other.Name && OtherData == other.OtherData;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hashCode = 0;

        unchecked
        {
           // whatever hash code computation you want, but for example...
            hashCode += 13 * Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0;
            hashCode += 13 * OtherData != null ? OtherData.GetHashCode() : 0;
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Once you do that, the query you have written will work just fine.

Comment: I see we think in similar ways! +1 for actually *showing* how to implement the methods.

Comment: Tough call on the "correct" answer - @dlev showed a workaround using LINQ, which is great since this is a one-off just to populate a treeview (my choice for this situation). However James provides a really great example of how to do this a little more "bullet proof" and would apply if I were doing more with this class.

Comment: @JYelton: No worries, just choose which one is the best solution for YOU and upvote the other as well and we'll both be happy.

Comment: For the current project, @dlev's LINQ method is what I used, but I believe implementing Equals/GetHashCode is the preferred way for most cases.

Answer (score 5):

The default comparer for `Owner` isn't working correctly (since it's just using reference equality) so `Distinct` thinks all the objects are different. One solution is to use two `Select`s:

```
var owners = MyWidgetList.Select(w => w.OwnerName).Distinct().Select(w => new Owner { Name = w }).ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could just implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `Owner`, and your original method would work.

Comment: This would mean remembering to do this in every query where only distinct values are required. Implementing IComparable is much neater

Comment: @jay I think `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` should do it, since internally `Distinct` just tries to add the next element to a set via its hashcode, and skip it if it's already there. That said, `IComparable` is also a fine choice.

Comment: +1 Thanks for showing the way to get this done in LINQ for now, which was more than suitable for the particular case I am dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

You owner object must implement `IComparable<>` for `Distinct` to work correctly. You will have to decide what makes an `Owner` the same as another `Owner`.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct uses equals to determine whether two element are the same. You could implement equals for your owner. Or select the name first like this:

```
List<Owner> Owners = MyWidgetList.Select(w => w.OwnerName).Distinct()
 .Select(s=>new Owner{Name = s}.ToList();
```

Comment: Your assuming Name is the unique identifier for the Owner object

Answer (score 0):

I guess this Distinct tries to get unique object from the `Owner` class you instantiated, why not just select the string

try this:

```
List<string> OwnersStr = MyWidgetList.Select(w =>  w.OwnerName).Distinct().ToList();
```

then create a list from them